# How can I tell if an application is written as a WebApp or native application?

Tags: iphone, android, html

There are cross-platform mobile application frameworks like Sencha Touch, which creates web apps with native look-and-feel. And frameworks like PhoneGap can pack them into an mobile application. How can I know if an application on Android or iPhone is written in a such way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decompile the bundle/APK.  For iPhone, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976699/decompile-iphone-app-binary).  An APK is just a modified JAR/ZIP file.  You should find pretty clear signs, such as the PhoneGap JS wrapper libraries, and/or HTML and JavaScript files in general.

On Android, you should find these [JavaScript files](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/tree/master/framework/assets/js), likely minified with [yuicompressor](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/tree/master/util/yuicompressor).

On iPhone, it's [this JavaScript](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/tree/master/PhoneGapLib/javascripts).