# Getting inside the iPhone app. Reverse engineering iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, reverse-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decompile iPhone app binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976699/decompile-iphone-app-binary)

**This question may be unethical or at least it belongs to the hacking area or the dark side of the iPhone development.**

I would like to take a look into the app without having a login (*there is no registration, it is not that everyone can have an account*).

Is it possible that I download it to the iPhone, transfer somehow the `IPA` file. Open it and take a look at the stuff that's there - e.g. resource files and xib files?

Do you know any successful approaches for reverse engineering the iPhone app downloaded from the app store.

**Any suggestions are welcomed!**

*Please do not support spam answers/statements that it is not moral/illegal.*

Comment: See also [Reverse Engineering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210945/reverse-engineering), [Is it possible to reverse-engineer my iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058203/is-it-possible-to-reverse-engineer-my-iphone-application), [How to protect app IPA from hacks if reverse engineering is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939222/how-to-protect-app-ipa-from-hacks-if-reverse-engineering-is-possible), among many others here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to look at an application that is installed onto the device, you will need to Jailbreak the device.

***This is legal to do, at least in the US. The Electronic Frontier Foundation successfully argued this a number of years ago, and it was [recently renewed](https://www.eff.org/press/releases/eff-wins-renewal-smartphone-jailbreaking-rights-plus-new-legal-protections-video).***

***Whether it is ethical or not, depends on what you want to do.***

Bear in mind that one of the first products designed by Steve Jobs and Steve Wozniak was a "Blue Box" - a device for making free phone calls. A certain amount of curiosity helps one to become a good engineer, especially if you want to specialize in security.

At the same time, the reason we have such a strong iOS industry now is because end-users can be reasonably assured that the apps they install will behave as advertised (and not get up to any funny-business).

Please ensure that you have a strong moral compass if you wish to proceed. Do not do anything unethical.

After jail-breaking the device, you can install ssh and scp. Place it on your local network and ssh in as root. Change to the:

```
/Application
```

. . .  directory and scp the .app file that you are interested to your local machine. Investigate.

Comment: Thank you Jasper for a constructive answer. I am not a cracker but a curious programmer. Haters will hate!

Comment: @reecon Note that if you want to have a look at the *code* of the app, you'll have to decrypt it first. It's not very difficult with gdb or some other tools, but is not trivial either.